# How can I retrieve the documentId of a document in Firestore collection in order to use it in a getter which returns a stream of objects

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, getter

I am playing around with developing a calorie tracking app using Flutter with Firebase. The database structure is set up so that when a user registers they are added to a user collection. When the user registers an 'entry' subcollection is created for the user. When the user logs in on any day, a document is added to the entry collection with the current date as its only field. When a user logs a food via the food diary, a 'foods' subcollection(nested subcollection within 'entries') is created and a document containing the name, calories and mealId (e.g. breakfast) of the food is added to the foods collection. In my widget which displays the food diary where users can log food and view food which has been logged, I have wrapped it in a Stream Provider to listen to changes from the db like so:

```
return StreamProvider<List<Food>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: userId).foods,
      child: Scaffold(
```

where 'Food' is a model I have created with the foodName, calories, and mealId (e.g. 'breakfast').
'DatabaseService' is a service I have created which has a getter to retrieve the list of foods from the database like so:

```
Stream<List<Food>> get foods {
      Firestore.instance.collection("users")
          .document(uid)
          .collection("entries")
          .where('entryDate', isEqualTo: "22/2/2021") //date hard-coded for now
          .getDocuments()
          .then((querySnapshot) {
        print(querySnapshot.documents); //for testing
        querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
          print("document id from within food stream getter is = " + result.documentID.toString()); //for testing - the correct documentId is printed here (important: there exists only 1 entry for each date so this querysnapshot will only ever contain 1 document
          String _doc1Id = result.documentID.toString();
          setDocumentId(_doc1Id); 
        });
      });
      print("user id from within food stream is " + documentId.toString()); //it says documentId is null in the console

    return Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(uid)
        .collection('entries')
        .document(documentId) //need documentId for this part of query - this query works correctly when documentId is hardcoded 
        .collection('foods')
        .snapshots()
      .map(foodListFromSnapshot);
    }

setDocumentId(String docId) {
    print("Set doc id called");
    print("doc Id passed in is: " + docId);
    documentId = docId;
    print("document Id is set to: " + documentId.toString());
  }

List<Food> foodListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Food(
        foodName: doc.data['foodName'] ?? '',
        calories: doc.data['calories'] ?? 0,
        mealId: doc.data['mealId'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

My issue is that I need to have the correct documentId for an 'entry' in order to retrieve the foods that were entered in that entry. As you can see above, I've attempted to set the documentId before the stream is returned, but the return statement is executed before the other code and returns an empty list. How can I somehow set the documentId before the getter tries to return the stream? I am very new to Flutter so don't have a great grasp of it yet, I have a feeling the issue is something to do with not 'await'ing either operation inside the function... however I have no idea if getters can be set up as Future functions to make use of async and await... Would appreciate any help.
This is the container within my FoodDiary widget where FoodList() widget is displayed.

```
child: Container(
                 width: 300,
                 height: 60,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                            ),
                 child: FoodList(),
                 ),
              ),
```

This is the FoodList() widget:

```
class FoodList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodListState createState() => _FoodListState();
}

class _FoodListState extends State<FoodList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool foodsNull = false;
    final foods = Provider.of<List<Food>>(context) ?? [];

    if(foods != null){
      print("foods list is not null"); //for testing
      print("length of list = " + foods.length.toString()); //for testing
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: foods.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("${foods[index].foodName.toString()} ${foods[index].calories.toString()} calories");
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("foods list is null");
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the breakfast container when the documentId for entry is hard-coded:
[breakfast container when documentId is hardcoded in getter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npieb.png)

Comment: Sorry if the structure of my question isn't great, this is my first time asking a question!

Comment: In your getter function `foods`, `getDocuments()` is a `Future`, that's why your `documentId` is NULL. And yes, you can use `async` `await` in getter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to use `then` to chain the result of the first get with the second get so that the code will wait for the first part to finish and only then run the second query, Something like this:

```
Stream<List<Food>> get foods {
    return Firestore.instance.collection("users")
        .document(uid)
        .collection("entries")
        .where('entryDate', isEqualTo: "22/2/2021") //date hard-coded for now
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
           return querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) => result.documentID.toString());
    }).then((docIds) {
      docId = docIds[0]
      return Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .document(uid)
          .collection('entries')
          .document(docId)
          .collection('foods')
          .snapshots()
          .map(foodListFromSnapshot);
    });
  }
```